# angularjs : watch of array has been triggered when the array in initial load and not being changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
               <div class="category">
                  <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="categories" selected-model="selectedCategories" extra-settings="categoriesSettings" translation-texts="customTexts"></div>
                </div>

  $scope.$watch('selectedCategories', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(oldValue);
    $scope.loadPosts();
  }, true);

  $scope.$watch('selectedCities', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    console.log(oldValue);
    $scope.loadPosts();
  }, true);
```

These two watches have been triggered when the page is initially loaded. Isn't it supposed not to trigger when the page is loading and the array not being changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct watcher's behavior. Adding `if (angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)) { return; }` inside callback will solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) (just before the first example)

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is
>   called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In
>   rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when
>   the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario
>   within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If
>   these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due
>   to initialization.

You could check if newValue !== oldValue to prevent it or create a variable that prevents the first check.